# Why are django.utils.timezone.make_aware and pytz.localize returning different results when dealing with DST?

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone, pytz

I'm using django 1.11 and pytz 2018.6

I'm having some problems understanding how django is dealing with DST.

My main problem is localizing the date `2018-11-04 00:00:00` in the `America/Sao_Paulo` timezone. According to the latest pytz version this is the date when DST starts in this timezone in 2018.

Well, on my application I started seeing the `pytz.exceptions.NonExistentTimeError` exception when trying to localize the mentioned date. The following code reproduces this exception:

```
import os
import datetime
import django
import pytz
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")
django.setup()
from django.utils.timezone import make_aware

sp = pytz.timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')
dst_start_date = datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 4, 0, 0, 0)
make_aware(dst_start_date, sp)
# Exception raised: pytz.exceptions.NonExistentTimeError: 2018-11-04 00:00:00
```

However, if I try to localize using `pytz.localize` instead of `make_aware` I get different results:

```
sp.localize(dst_start_date) # Returns 2018-11-04 00:00:00-03:00
```

I expected to receive the same exception when trying to localize. But it didn't raise the exception and actually returned a wrong result (the `-03:00` offset is when we're not on DST. On the specific date I was expecting the `2018-11-04 00:00:00-03:00` date to be converted to `2018-11-04 00:00:00-02:00`).

This confuses me, because reading the `make_aware` code in `django.utils.timezone` I understood the same `pytz.tzinfo.localize` method is called.

```
# django.utils.timezone
def make_aware(value, timezone=None, is_dst=None):
    """
    Makes a naive datetime.datetime in a given time zone aware.
    """
    if timezone is None:
        timezone = get_current_timezone()
    if hasattr(timezone, 'localize'):
        # This method is available for pytz time zones.
        return timezone.localize(value, is_dst=is_dst)
    else:
        # Check that we won't overwrite the timezone of an aware datetime.
        if is_aware(value):
            raise ValueError(
                "make_aware expects a naive datetime, got %s" % value)
        # This may be wrong around DST changes!
        return value.replace(tzinfo=timezone)
```

Why are both results different? Why I'm not getting an exception when manually trying to localize the date `2018-11-04 00:00:00` to `America/Sao_Paulo`?

Please make sure you have the latest pytz version (`pip install pytz --upgrade`) before trying this code because we had a change on the DST date this year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is the `is_dst` parameter passed to `localize`. When you call it yourself but leave it off, it defaults to `False`. In the `make_aware` code you posted it defaults to `None`.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly it! Thanks!